# Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\binom{2n}{n}2^{-n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, binomial-coefficients

I would like to show that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\binom{2n}{n}2^{-n} = \infty$$
I have gotten as far as:
$$
\binom{2n}{n}={(2n)!\over (n!)^2}=\left({n\over1}+1\right)\left({n\over2}+1\right)(\dots)\left({n\over n}+1\right)\ge2^n
$$
But the $2^{⁻n}$ factor defeats that attempt, any suggestion on how to continue would be most appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Ratio test http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#The_test

Comment: It's overkill for this problem, but ${2n\choose n} 2^{-n}$
actually grows as a multiple of $2^n/\sqrt{n}$, and thus clearly
approaches $\infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ (and yes, by Stirling
the constant is $1/\sqrt\pi$).  There are several more-or-less elementary
proofs of that in the replies to this MathOverflow question:
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/133732

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** Keep the first bracket $({n\over1}+1)$ unchanged:

$$\binom{2n}{n}={(2n)!\over (n!)^2}=({n\over1}+1)({n\over2}+1)(\dots)({n\over n}+1)\ge2^{n-1}(n+1)$$

Answer (score 1):

Using [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), we see that

$$n! \sim \frac{n^n}{e^n} \sqrt{2\pi n}$$

Thus, we have

$${2n \choose n} = \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} \sim \frac{(2n)^{2n} \sqrt{4\pi n} / e^{2n}}{(n^n\sqrt{2\pi n} / e^n)^2} = \frac{4^n (n^2)^n \sqrt{2} \sqrt{2\pi n}}{n^{2n} (2\pi n)} = \frac{4^n \sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{n}}$$

which tends to infinity as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Look at row $2n$ in the Pascal triangle. The sum of all terms is $2^{2n}= 4^n$. Moreover, the central binomial coefficient is the largest number in that row and so $4^n \le (2n+1){{2n} \choose n}$.
Hence
$$
{{2n} \choose n} \ge \frac{4^n}{2n+1}
$$
and so
$$
{{2n} \choose n}2^{-n} \ge \frac{2^n}{2n+1} \to \infty
$$

Answer (score 0):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324549/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracnn2-diverges-to-infinity/339666#339666).

**Hint:**
You can use the result

> If $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=a$ and $|a|<1$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty}{a_n}=0 $ and the $\lim_{n\to \infty}{a_n}=\infty$ if $|a|>1$. $

Comment: @CalvinLin: Yo are right. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: In fact, it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the following facts to get a lower bound on $\binom{2n}{n}$.

- $\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}$=$\left ( \binom{2n}{0} + \binom{2n}{2n} \right )+ \sum_{k=1}^{2n-1} \binom{2n}{k}$ = $2^{2n}$
- The maximum value of $\binom{2n}{k}$ is attained at $\binom{2n}{n}$

Thus:

$$\binom{2n}{n} \geq \frac{2^{2n}}{2n}$$

and so:

$$\binom{2n}{n}2^{-n} \geq \frac{2^n}{2n}$$

Using L'Hospital's rule to take the limit of the RHS we get $\lim_{n\to \infty}2^{n-1}\ln2 = \infty$.