# Problem proving inequality $\frac{4^n}{n+1}\leq \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$

Tags: inequality, induction, binomial-coefficients, factorial, fractions

I skip the base case $n=0$ because it's obvious.

I know that this is very equivalent to: [Prove by induction: $\frac{2^{2n}}{n+1}<\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2},n>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1500512/prove-by-induction-frac22nn1-frac2nn2-n1)

But I try to learn some tricks so maybe you can help me?

Assumption: $\frac{4^n}{n+1}\leq \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\iff 4^n\leq\frac{(n+1)(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$ for some n.

Step: $n\to n+1$

$4^{n+1}=\frac{(n+2)(2n+2)!}{((n+1)!)^2}$

I begin with manipulating the LHS:

$4^{n+1}=4\cdot4^n\leq ???$

$???\leq\frac{(2n)!(2n+2)(2n+1)(n+1)}{(n!(n+1))}$

$=\frac{(n+1)(2n+2)!}{((n+1)!)^2}$

Note that I want to work my way from both sides to the mid where I get a very easy to check inequality by assumption.

Can you help me?

Comment: hint: using binomial coefficients (more precisely, consider $(1+1)^{2n}$) and forget about induction:)

Comment: See also: 
[Prove that $\binom{2n}{n}>\frac{4n}{n+1}\forall \; n\geq 2, n\in \mathbb{N}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1954608). (As already said in the previous comment, noticing that it is a binomial coefficient might be useful.)

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/518386/589.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{4^{n+1}}{(n+2)} < \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\frac{4(n+1)}{(n+2)}$$
Now $$\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\frac{4(n+1)}{(n+2)} = \frac{(2n+2)!}{((n+1)!)^2}\frac{4(n+1)^3}{(n+2)(2n+1)(2n+2)}$$
So $$\frac{4(n+1)^3}{(n+2)(2n+1)(2n+2)} <1 $$ implies $$\frac{(2n+2)!}{((n+1)!)^2}\frac{4(n+1)^3}{(n+2)(2n+1)(2n+2)} <\frac{(2n+2)!}{((n+1)!)^2} $$, for $n \gt 1$.

Comment: Hi, I can follow, but how do you get $\frac{4^{n+1}}{(n+2)} < \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\frac{4}{(n+2)}$. The 4 on the RHS makes sense. But why (n+2) in the denominator?

Comment: I understood, thanks :)